# Stuck at hasSpaceAvailable and Can't read from NSInputStream

Tags: swift, macos, tcp, network-programming, nsstream

I got a problem when handling the stream events. I have a client app which connect to a server via TCP and constantly receive JSON datas from server.

so far, I create the stream like this:

```
// Create Stream

var readStream : Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
var writeStream : Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

let host : CFString = NSString(string: serverUrl!)
let port : UInt32 = UInt32(serverPort)

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, &readStream, &writeStream)

inputStream = readStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

inputStream!.delegate = self
outputStream!.delegate = self

inputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
outputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

inputStream!.open()
outputStream!.open()

// Send Authentication Data

let uid = 1000000000 + arc4random() % 2000000000
let joinRoomMsg : NSData = "{\"roomid\": \(realRoomID!), \"uid\": \(uid)}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

sendSocketData(outputStream!, totalLength: joinRoomMsg.length + 16, headerLength: 16, protocolVersion: 1, action: 7, param5: 1, data: joinRoomMsg)
```

here is `sendSocketData` func:

```
func sendSocketData(outputStream: NSOutputStream, totalLength: Int32, headerLength: CShort, protocolVersion: CShort, action: Int32, param5: Int32, data: NSData?) {

    var totalLengthBE = totalLength.bigEndian
    var headerLengthBE = headerLength.bigEndian
    var protocolVersionBE = protocolVersion.bigEndian
    var actionBE = action.bigEndian
    var param5BE = param5.bigEndian

    withUnsafePointers(&totalLengthBE, &headerLengthBE, &protocolVersionBE) {
        outputStream.write(UnsafePointer($0), maxLength: sizeofValue(totalLengthBE))
        outputStream.write(UnsafePointer($1), maxLength: sizeofValue(headerLengthBE))
        outputStream.write(UnsafePointer($2), maxLength: sizeofValue(protocolVersionBE))
    }

    withUnsafePointers(&actionBE, &param5BE) {
        outputStream.write(UnsafePointer($0), maxLength: sizeofValue(actionBE))
        outputStream.write(UnsafePointer($1), maxLength: sizeofValue(param5BE))
    }

    if data != nil {
        outputStream.write(UnsafePointer(data!.bytes), maxLength: data!.length)
    }
}
```

handling:

```
func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {
    if aStream === inputStream {
        switch eventCode {
        case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
            print("iStream ErrorOccurred")
        case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
            print("iStream EndEncountered")
        case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
            print("iStream Opened")
        case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
            print("Stream HasBytesAvailable")
            // read data here...
        default:
            print("iStream Unknow")
        }
    } else if aStream === outputStream {
        switch eventCode {
        case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
            print("oStream Opened")
        case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
            print("oStream ErrorOccurred")
        case NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:
            print("oStream HasSpaceAvailable")
        default:
            print("oStream Unknow")
        }
    }
}
```

the server did send JSON datas back to me.

[image: Screenshot]

And now I should able to read datas from inputStream with eventCode `NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable`.

**But the problem is:** the stream events handler send me the `NSStreamEvent.HsaSpaceAvailable` and stuck here. `inputStream.hasBytesAvailable` return `false` and I was unable to read anything.

According to [Stream Programing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002274-BAJCABBC):

> If the delegate receives an `NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable` event and does not write anything to the stream, it does not receive further space-available events from the run loop until the `NSOutputStream` object receives more bytes. When this happens, the run loop is restarted for space-available events.

But I have **no** data to write to the stream any more.

I did try to write some random data to it but no luck.
I also try send Authentication Data after `outputStream.hasSpaceAvailable` return `true` but it did nothing either.

Is there any wrong with my code?

Comment: After updating to Swift 3 I was able to receive data in `NSStream`'s delegate method `stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent)` with no error. I think it just another bug of Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized the stream() function did not work just because the signature of this function is incorrect/obsolete.

Here is what you are using:

```
func stream(aStream: Stream, handleEvent eventCode: Stream.Event)
```

But really it should be:

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event)
```